# Calculate running total for each {country,city,year,month} group

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, cumulative-sum

I need to calculate the running total per each country, city, year and month from a join of two tables. The query with all the data is this one:

**Edit: The join operation with the TD_MONTH table is not mandatory.**

```
SELECT costs.CITY,
         costs.COUNTRY,
         months.ID,
         costs.ID_YEAR,
         SUM (costs.AMOUNT) AMOUNT
    FROM    TH_COSTS costs
         JOIN
            TD_MONTH months
         ON (costs.ID_MES = months.YEARMONTH)
GROUP BY costs.COUNTRY,
         costs.CITY,
         costs.ID_YEAR,
         months.ID
ORDER BY costs.COUNTRY,
         costs.CITY,
         costs.ID_YEAR,
         months.ID;
```

Which results on this grid:

```
+---------+--------+-------+------+-----------+
| Country |  City  | Month | Year |  Amount   |
+---------+--------+-------+------+-----------+
| Spain   | Madrid |     4 | 2014 | 396061,7  |
| Spain   | Madrid |     5 | 2014 | 315725,25 |
| Spain   | Madrid |     6 | 2014 | 16390     |
| Spain   | Madrid |     7 | 2014 | 85296     |
| Spain   | Madrid |     8 | 2014 | 10443,25  |
| Spain   | Madrid |    12 | 2014 | 17500     |
| Spain   | Madrid |     1 | 2015 | 353566    |
| Spain   | Madrid |     2 | 2015 | 382729    |
| Spain   | Madrid |     3 | 2015 | 261026    |
| Spain   | Madrid |     4 | 2015 | 304258    |
| Spain   | Madrid |     5 | 2015 | 259893    |
| Spain   | Madrid |     6 | 2015 | 217296    |
| Spain   | Madrid |     7 | 2015 | 461769    |
| Spain   | Madrid |     8 | 2015 | 456990,5  |
| Spain   | Madrid |     9 | 2015 | 219020    |
| Spain   | Madrid |    10 | 2015 | 242796    |
| Spain   | Madrid |    11 | 2015 | 134197    |
| Spain   | Madrid |    12 | 2015 | 91901,9   |
+---------+--------+-------+------+-----------+
```

And from the one above I need the next as result:

```
+---------+--------+-------+------+-----------+
| Country |  City  | Month | Year |  Amount   |
+---------+--------+-------+------+-----------+
| Spain   | Madrid |     1 | 2014 | 0         |
| Spain   | Madrid |     2 | 2014 | 0         |
| Spain   | Madrid |     3 | 2014 | 0         |
| Spain   | Madrid |     4 | 2014 | 396061,7  |
| Spain   | Madrid |     5 | 2014 | 711786,95 |
| Spain   | Madrid |     6 | 2014 | 728176,95 |
| Spain   | Madrid |     7 | 2014 | 813472,95 |
| Spain   | Madrid |     8 | 2014 | 823916,2  |
| Spain   | Madrid |     9 | 2014 | 841416,2  |
| Spain   | Madrid |    10 | 2014 | 1194982,2 |
| Spain   | Madrid |    11 | 2014 | 1577711,2 |
| Spain   | Madrid |    12 | 2014 | 1595211,2 |
| Spain   | Madrid |     1 | 2015 | 353566    |
| Spain   | Madrid |     2 | 2015 | 736295    |
| Spain   | Madrid |     3 | 2015 | 997321    |
| Spain   | Madrid |     4 | 2015 | 1301579   |
| Spain   | Madrid |     5 | 2015 | 1561472   |
| Spain   | Madrid |     6 | 2015 | 1778768   |
| Spain   | Madrid |     7 | 2015 | 2240537   |
| Spain   | Madrid |     8 | 2015 | 2697527,5 |
| Spain   | Madrid |     9 | 2015 | 2916547,5 |
| Spain   | Madrid |    10 | 2015 | 3159343,5 |
| Spain   | Madrid |    11 | 2015 | 3293540,5 |
| Spain   | Madrid |    12 | 2015 | 3385442,4 |
+---------+--------+-------+------+-----------+
```

**Edit: fields on the starting table:**

```
+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+---------+------+
| AMOUNT_1 | AMOUNT_2 | STREET | CITY 1 | MONTH  | CITY 2 | CONTINENT | COUNTRY | YEAR |
+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+---------+------+
```

The first thing that came to mind is using four nested loops, but that's a huge time-consuming solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with something like the following:

```
with test(Country, City, Year, Month,amount) as
(
  select 'Spain', 'Madrid', 2014, 4, 1 from dual union all
  select 'Spain', 'Madrid', 2014, 5, 1 from dual union all
  select 'Spain', 'Madrid', 2014, 6, 1 from dual union all
  select 'Spain', 'Madrid', 2014, 7, 1 from dual union all
  select 'Spain', 'Madrid', 2014, 8, 1 from dual union all
  select 'Spain', 'Madrid', 2014, 9, 1 from dual union all
  select 'Spain', 'Madrid', 2014, 10, 1 from dual union all
  select 'Spain', 'Madrid', 2014, 11, 1 from dual union all
  select 'Spain', 'Madrid', 2014, 12, 1 from dual union all
  select 'Spain', 'Madrid', 2015, 1, 1 from dual union all
  select 'Spain', 'Madrid', 2015, 2, 1 from dual union all
  select 'UK', 'London', 2014, 7, 10 from dual union all
  select 'UK', 'London', 2014, 8, 10 from dual union all
  select 'UK', 'London', 2014, 9, 10 from dual union all
  select 'UK', 'London', 2014, 10, 10 from dual union all
  select 'UK', 'London', 2014, 11, 10 from dual union all
  select 'UK', 'London', 2014, 12, 10 from dual union all
  select 'UK', 'London', 2015, 1, 10 from dual union all
  select 'UK', 'London', 2015, 2, 10 from dual 
)
select country, city, year, month,
       sum(amount) over ( partition by country, city, year order by month)
from test
```

It computes the running total, ordering by month and grouping by year, country and city

Comment: It returns duplicate rows, how could I delete them?

Comment: What result are you having? It returns exactly the same number of rows than the starting table, with the running total for each row

Comment: I've edited the main post to show the remaining fields

Comment: If you need to handle more fields, with the same logics than country and state, you can simply add them in the `partition by` clause